# Collapse all tabs in an accordion (not jQuery UI)

Tags: jquery, toggle, accordion, slide, visible

I made a little accordion which works fine, but I'd like to add the functionality that you also can close all boxes.

In [this DEMO](http://liveweave.com/8ChYy6) you can see, that there is never more than one box open.
See the jQuery code below:

```
$(function() {
  $('.job_content .job_description_box').hide();
  $('.job_box:first').addClass('active').next().slideDown('slow');
  $('.job_box').click(function() {
    if($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
        $('.job_box').removeClass('active').next().slideUp('slow');
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown('slow');
        $(".downarrow", this).toggleClass( ".uparrow" );
    }
  });
});
```

Now if you click on the opened box it should collapse. This was my try, which unfortunately doesn't work:

```
if($(this).find('.job_description_box').is(':visible')) {
  $(this).slideUp('slow');
}
```

–––

For those who looked at the demo: I'm talking about the blue job boxes at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    if($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
        $('.job_box').removeClass('active').next().slideUp('slow');
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown('slow');
        $(".downarrow", this).toggleClass( ".uparrow" );
 }
  else
  {
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideUp('slow');
  }
```

I have added an 'else' statement to your current 'if' statement to hide the content upon clicking the box again.

EDIT:
Add this to your CSS file.  This will rotate your arrow rather than using another image.

```
.arrow_rotate {
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg); 
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg;
     transform: rotate(180deg);
```

}

Update your JQuery:

```
 $('.job_box').click(function() {
    if($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
        $('.job_box').removeClass('active').next().slideUp('slow');
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown('slow');
        $(".downarrow", this).addClass('arrow_rotate');
 }
 else
  {
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideUp('slow');
                $(".downarrow", this).removeClass('arrow_rotate');
  }
```

This should now do as you require.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. One little question: do you know why that arrow-changer isn't working? ".downarrow" should change to ".uparrow" when slided out. I thought I placed it right, but it doesn't work.

Comment: This is the CSS: `.downarrow { height: 16px; content:url(http://i.stack.imgur.com/3pWmF.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; }

.uparrow { height: 16px; content:url(http://i.stack.imgur.com/H3aSv.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; }
`

Comment: It's still not working. Can you please have a look at my [Liveweave document](http://liveweave.com/2wuDDJ)?

Comment: Hmm,  I just had a look at that document and it seems that you are not displaying the arrows anymore?

Comment: Well if so, then not intentionally. I have this HTML `<div class="slide_button"></div> <div class="helper"> <div class="arrow downarrow"></div> </div>` and this CSS `.arrow { position: relative; top: calc(50% - 8px); margin: 0 auto; } .downarrow { height: 16px; content:url('http://i.stack.imgur.com/f56Aq.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; z-index: 1000; } .uparrow { height: 16px; content:url('http://i.stack.imgur.com/J4ErT.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; z-index: 1000; }`